# Не работает парсинг в боте aiogram когда пишешь текст выдает новости только в консоли а в бота не выдает

Tags: python, парсер, aiogram

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests



bot = Bot(token='')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

#команда старт
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет я бот который выдаст тебе самые актуальные новости, просто напиши "Новости"')






#парсер
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def get_news(message):

    url = 'https://news.rambler.ru'

    page = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

    filteredNews = []
    allNews = soup.findAll('a', class_='_6bF6i')



    for data in allNews:
        if data.find('div', class_='_1tnKf') is not None:
            filteredNews.append(data.text)
    for data in filteredNews:
        print(data)

    return filteredNews

@dp.message_handler()
async def pars(message: types.message):
    await bot.send_message(get_news)
   
    
    






if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо
`print` - `await message.answer(data)`.
Ну и await `bot.send_message(get_news)` вызывается с параметром `message`.

Comment: Спасибо большое!